# Idiom equivalent to "when it rains, it pours"

Tags: idioms

In English, the idiom "when it rains, it pours" is used to say that when one bad thing happens, other bad things often accompany it.

From the [Merriam-Webster dictionary's online example](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/when%20it%20rains%2C%20it%20pours):

> The team not only lost the game but three of its best players were injured. When it rains, it pours.

**Is there an equivalent idiom in Italian?**

I found [one source](https://www.thinkinitalian.com/italian-idioms/#Funny_idioms_about_life) suggesting this might be equivalent:

> Piove sul bagnato.  (tr: "It rains on wet ground.")

Comment: _Piove sul bagnato_ may also (and perhaps mainly) mean something like “Rich get richer”, who has something will get even more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possibility is the phrase *i guai non vengono mai da soli* or *le disgrazie* *non vengono mai da sole*, meaning that troubles are followed by troubles, literally *troubles don't come alone.*

See for instance:

https://it.glosbe.com/it/en/i%20guai%20non%20vengono%20mai%20da%20soli